# handling checked checkboxes PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a table that takes data from the database like so: (Is not a form)

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        echo "<table id='logs' border='1' cellspacing='0' width='62%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Time Registered</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Username</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Password</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>IP Address</th>";
        echo "<th width='2%'><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"checkAll(this);\">Mark</a></th>";
        echo "<th width='2%'>Delete</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo ("<p><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td><i>$row[3]</i></td><td><center><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mark[]\"/></center></td><td><a href=\"delete.php?time=$row[2]&user=$row[0]&pass=$row[1]&ip=$row[3]\"><center>[x]</center></a></td></p>");
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
}
```

The part `<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mark[]\"/>` is the checkbox. How can I find and handle the checked checkboxes?

```
if(mark[$checked]) {
     //delete data from database if row checked
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($_REQUEST['mark'] as $value){
    echo "$value was selected\n <br />";
}
```

if you want to know which one wasn't selected then store all possible selections into an array and walk ofer this array and do someting like

```
foreach($poss_select as $key=>$val){
    if(!in_array($val,$_REQUEST['mark']){
        $not_selected[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        deleteRow($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST[ 'mark' ]` will be an array of all of the checked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some AJAX or a form submit to pass that checkbox data to PHP for processing.

But before you can do that, you would need to include a value attribute on those checkboxes.  Currently, $_POST['mark'] (if you used POST to submit the form) would be a 0-based array of the checked checkboxes (and only the checked ones).

I would recommend outputting the user id as the value of checkbox to help out with identifying the marked users.

Then you could do

```
foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $marked) {
    // $marked would contain the value attribute of the checked checkboxes
    // and you could run a SQL query for each value of $marked.
}
```