# insert values from multiple checkbox into database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [handling checked checkboxes PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489770/handling-checked-checkboxes-php)

i have this problem. I have a webpage that show car registration number and it's violation. And we can change the status of the violation from 1=not treated to 2=treated. I want to use multiple check box to choose which car registration status that i want to change 
here's the screenshot of my web

[image])

how i change the status of both car registration number ?
here's my webpage code

```
 <div id="content">
    <div class="content_item">
    <?php
       $con = mysql_connect("localhost","fpjarmul","fpjarmul");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("fpjarmul", $con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM laporan WHERE status = '1'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {?>
            <form action="ubahdata.php" method="post">
                <input type="checkbox" name="idlaporan" value="<?php echo $row['idlaporan'] ?>" /><?php echo "ID : {$row['idlaporan']}" ?><br />
                <?php echo  "Nomor Polisi : {$row['platkendaraan']} <br>" .
                            "Status : {$row['status']} <br>" . 
                            "Tanggal Laporan : {$row['tanggallapor']} <br><br>"; ?>

        <?php   
        } 
        ?>  
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

and here's my script

```
 <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","fpjarmul","fpjarmul");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("fpjarmul", $con);

 $sql=("UPDATE laporan set status='2' where idlaporan='$_POST[idlaporan]'");

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
?> 
 <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I saw this question at least 5 times here in SO, did you Google it ?

Comment: yes, but i dont understand what i'm looking at, so i try to ask the direct question. 
maybe you can give me the links to those 5 question
it will help me a lot :)

Comment: I got another idea, why won't you take the code that you don't understand, go over it line-by-line, and try to figure it out ? it will be better for you than someone handing a "ready made" code that works - you might not be able to maintain it...

Comment: BTW, if you have a specific question - a specific line of code that you don't understand how it works - I'll help you gladly!

Comment: You can start with thfollowing tip: don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: okay, what i dont understand is, how i send multiple values from the checkbox. I'm succeeding only in sending 1 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following approach:

1. Change the checkbox 'name' as 'idlaporan[]' (<input type="checkbox" name="idlaporan[]" )
2. After form submit, selected check box values will be present in the Server side array $_POST['idlaporan']
3. Use a foreach loop to update values in database.

   ```
   foreach ($_POST['idlaporan'] as $idlaporan) {

       $sql=("UPDATE laporan set status='2' where idlaporan='$idlaporan'");    
       if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
       }
       echo "1 record added<br/>";    
   }
   ```